# Preload elements for Flux.generate(...)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm creating a Flux using Flux.generate(). The generator (Consumer) is actually reading from a message queue. The problem is that this call takes quite a long time (occasionally 1-2 seconds even). This will make the flux to stop processing.

```
package com.github.loa.vault.service.listener;

import com.github.loa.document.service.domain.DocumentType;
import com.github.loa.queue.service.QueueManipulator;
import com.github.loa.queue.service.domain.Queue;
import com.github.loa.queue.service.domain.message.DocumentArchivingMessage;
import com.github.loa.vault.service.domain.DocumentArchivingContext;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.SynchronousSink;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class VaultQueueConsumer implements Consumer<SynchronousSink<DocumentArchivingContext>> {

    private final QueueManipulator queueManipulator;

    @Override
    public void accept(final SynchronousSink<DocumentArchivingContext> documentSourceItemSynchronousSink) {
        final DocumentArchivingMessage documentArchivingMessage = (DocumentArchivingMessage)
                queueManipulator.readMessage(Queue.DOCUMENT_ARCHIVING_QUEUE);

        documentSourceItemSynchronousSink.next(
                DocumentArchivingContext.builder()
                        .type(DocumentType.valueOf(documentArchivingMessage.getType()))
                        .source(documentArchivingMessage.getSource())
                        .content(documentArchivingMessage.getContent())
                        .build()
        );
    }
}
```

Obviously adding `parallel` doesn't help because the generator is still being called one at a time.

```
Flux.generate(vaultQueueConsumer)
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel()) 
    .flatMap(vaultDocumentManager::archiveDocument)
    .subscribe();
```

Does anybody know how to make the generator parallel? I don't want to use `Flux.create()` because then I would lose backpressure.

Comment: what are you going to make parallel? Reading from empty blocking queue?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Yes, reading from an Apache Artemis queue in parallel. I have multiple connections open and don't care about message acknowledgment (messages are pre-acknowledged by the server).

Comment: why don't you read from Apache Artemis queue as it is described in the documentation? any additional wrappers like Flux only add overhead and reduce parallelism.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov My whole application is reactive (database drivers etc) and as far as I know Artemis doesn't provide any reactive drivers.

Comment: If  Artemis doesn't provide reactive drivers, then there is absolutely no sense to read Artemis queues using reactive streams.  Reactive streams require that all parties obey the reactive protocol. Since Artemis queue does not, using it as a publisher or subscriber will only cause errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
Mono.just(1).repeat()  // create infinite flux, maybe there is a nicer way for that?
    .flatMap(this::readFromQueue, 100) // define queue polling concurrency
    .flatMap(this::archiveDocument)
    .subscribe();
```

```java
private Mono<String> readFromQueue(Integer ignore)
{
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(1500); // your actual blocking queue polling here
        return "queue_element";
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()); // dedicate blocking call to threadpool
}
```

Comment: I'm still not fully satisfied with this one but it's better for sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `vaultQueueConsumer` includes slow operation. 
So, the solution is to extract this slow operation from `generate` to `map` that can be parallelised.

As an idea you can generate a queue name where the messages have to be consumed from and do the actual message consumption in a `map` method after making flux parallel:

```
String queue = "test";
Flux.<String>generate(synchronousSink -> synchronousSink.next(queue))
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .map(queueManipulator::readMessage)
    .doOnNext(log::info)
    .subscribe();
```

The fake `QueueManipulator` sleeps 1-2 seconds before returning a message:

```
public class QueueManipulator {

  private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

  public String readMessage(String queue) {
    sleep(); //sleep 1-2 seconds
    return queue + " " + counter.incrementAndGet();
  }
  //...
}
```

This way message consumption is done in parallel:

```
12:49:22.362 [parallel-4] - test 2
12:49:22.362 [parallel-3] - test 4
12:49:22.362 [parallel-2] - test 1
12:49:22.362 [parallel-1] - test 3
12:49:23.369 [parallel-3] - test 6
12:49:23.369 [parallel-1] - test 5
12:49:23.369 [parallel-2] - test 7
12:49:23.369 [parallel-4] - test 8
```

This solution above is straightforward buy may look like a "hack".

Another idea is to call `Flux.generate` inside `flatMap`:

```
String queue = "test";
int parallelism = 5;
Flux.range(0, parallelism)
    .flatMap(i ->
        Flux.<String>generate(synchronousSink -> {
          synchronousSink.next(queueManipulator.readMessage(queue));
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()))
    .doOnNext(log::info)
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: Uhh interesting and creative. :) It solves the problem but I feel that this is quite a hack and not a "proper" solution.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty for a working solution. ;)

Comment: I updated the answer with another solution that may look less hacky :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Flux.generate(vaultQueueConsumer)
 .parallel()
 .runOn(Schedulers.parallel()) 
 .flatMap(vaultDocumentManager::archiveDocument)
 .subscribe();
```

Comment: Unfortunately yes I did. The problem is that even if I enable parallel then the processing is slow because `queueManipulator.readMessage(Queue.DOCUMENT_ARCHIVING_QUEUE)` takes a long time.